# JPA @ManyToMany with List of LIsts

Tags: hibernate, mapping

Hi Guys i need Help..

```
class model{
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
          name="MOD_KOMP",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="MOD_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
          inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="KOMP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
private List<List<KatalogKomponente>> katalogKomponentenListe;}
```

}

```
class KatalogKomponente{@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="katalogKomponentenListe", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Model> _modele;}
```

ERROR MSG: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.bf.scm.schuhverwaltung.model.Model.katalogKomponentenListe[java.util.List]

what is the issue? i dont get it...

THX

Comment: You most probably want a List<KatalogKomponente>, not a List<List<KatalogKomponente>>.

Comment: hi, no i want a list of a list

Comment: Well, you can't. Not in a JPA entity. You need to think about how your data will be stored in the database. You need to put yourself in Hibernate shoes. What would it do with that list of lists. How would it construct it back from the data in the database?

Comment: so.... ok... if i create a class with only with a list of KatalogKomponente and put the objekt in a list?

Comment: I don't know. What are you trying to achieve? What is this list of list? How and why are components grouped together?